# Algolia Key Value Search

Tags: node.js, meteor, algolia

I am currently working with the Algolia search API and I am unable to figure out how I would limit the results by `key` `value` searching + query string. By this i mean this.

I have a list of properties.
Each property belongs to a client.

Within the application If i am looking at a client information card and I want to search for a property that client owns It would make more sense to limit the results to the client and then look for the query string.

I am using MongoDB as my DB and storing the client id as a sub document like so

```
//Property Document
{
 _id : "randomID"
 client : {
  _id : "randomID",
  name : "ClientName"
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to restrict the search to a specific `client`, I would go for facet filtering to restrict the search to that client only.

- Add `client._id` in the `attributesForFaceting` in your index settings
- Filter your searches with the `facetFilters=client._id:MYCLIENTID` query parameter

Then, you should also take a look at the [Secured API keys](https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#secured-api-keys) which are able to encode such restriction in a secure way (so the end-user cannot patch the JS code and work-around the filtering).

Comment: I am getting an `Invalid parameter: attributesForFaceting'` error when i try this. My code looks like this https://gist.github.com/patrickml/c5d71e296319ffaba1cb

Comment: It ended up being the fact that i was literally using the wrong parameter. the correct param is simply `facets` I also did need to go the the dashboard and add the facet. Personally i feel like this is a hack way of doing this, i wonder if there is another way. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: `attributesForFaceting` is an index setting, not a query parameter; that's why you get the error.

Comment: If you want to do it in a secure way, you should look at the Secured API keys https://www.algolia.com/doc/javascript#secured-api-keys which are basically encoding those filters in the API keys. It's really the way to go, nothing hacky there :)

Comment: I keep getting a 403 Forbidden response when using a Secured API key. My arguments to the `generate_secured_api_key` method are (MY_SECRET_KEY, 'facetFilters=participants%3Asome-participant-id').  @redox - any ideas as to why those arguments aren't correctly generating a secure key?

Comment: I figured out what was wrong. Instead of MY_SECRET_KEY, I had to use a search key. In retrospect, it seems like a silly mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1):

There is parameter called `restrictSearchableAttributes`[[link]](https://www.algolia.com/doc/ruby#param-restrictSearchableAttributes) to restrict, at query time, search to some attributes only. Nevertheless, in your case I think you'd get more accurate results by putting each `client info` into a different record (+ the info of the related document).

Comment: Sadly this isnt what im looking for :/ im not trying to limit the fields that i search im trying to set basicly the following logic in the search `(client._id === "SomeID") && AnyDocumentsWithSomeInputedText` basicly only return documents with the correct client._id that contain elsewhere in the document my search query